# Tor Hidden Service Suddenly Stopped Working

Tags: onion-routing, address

I setup my hidden service a in February and has been working completely fine. After 9 days of not having my service running 20th-29th March, Tor keeps on giving me the error "We can’t connect to the server at xxxxxx.onion". I have not touched anything.

My localhost:8080 is working fine and NGINX is logging activity as normal.
From doing some research, I think maybe my generated onion is no longer working for some reason?

How would I go about creating a new onion address for my hidden service?

Thank you.

**EDIT (Solution):**

- See answer below!

Comment: Thanks for posting a solution, and feel free to add and accept your own answer so that other people can see that you solved it :)

Comment: What you should do is investigate why the sudden stop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add another hidden service directory in the torrc.conf file & restart your Tor service with `sudo service tor restart`.

Medium has a great tutorial on setting up a hidden service on Tor:

https://medium.com/@ajphillips/how-to-create-your-own-tor-hidden-service-436bece8602f